# Define command that accepts \\ in arguments

Tags: macros, errors, align

I am trying to define a new command `\dfix` that can handle newlines in its arguments. The command works as expected when the arguments have no `\\` in them, but LaTeX produces errors if I do include newline characters.

How can I create a command/macro that is safe with regard to line breaks?

I would like `\dfix` in the following context

```
\begin{align*}
  &\dfix{(A\\
  &B)}{C}
\end{align*
```

to produce the same output as

```
\begin{align*}
  &(A\\
  &B)^\ddag_{C}
\end{align*}
```

Similarly, `$\dfix{A}{B}$` should produce the same output as `$A^\ddag_B$`.

Here is a MWE defining the command and trying to us it in various places.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dfix}[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}^\ddag_{#2}}}
\begin{document}
% This causes: ./mwe.tex:9: Missing } inserted.
\begin{align*}
  &\dfix{A\\
  &B}{C}
\end{align*}
% This is OK
\begin{align*}
  &\dfix{A B}{C}
\end{align*}
% This also produces errors.
\begin{multline*}
  \dfix{A\\
    B}{C}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So what do you expect when using your command with many lines?

Comment: you don't say what you expect the output to be. in that context the `\\ ` is ending the row of the align, but it is inside a group (it is the group that causes the error not the newcommand)

Comment: Easy way to enable multiline arguments: `\newcommand{\dfix}[2]{\ensuremath{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}^\ddag_{#2}}}` but that still wouldn't make `\dfix{A\\&B}{C}` valid syntax. What do you want `\dfix` to do?

Comment: the macro has to expand to something that is valid in the align, so you can show the intended result by showing a working `align` that does not use `\dfix` but makes the result you want. I can not guess from the code above,

Comment: I just edited the question to add an example showing the desired behaviour.

Comment: I answered, there is no way I would ever have guessed that was the desired output from the initial question! You hadn't mentioned adding `()` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you ask but seems a very weird construct, are you sure this is what you need?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dfix}[2]{(#1)^\ddag_{#2}}
\begin{document}
% This causes: ./mwe.tex:9: Missing } inserted.
\begin{align*}
  &\dfix{A\\
  &B}{C}
\end{align*}
% This is OK
\begin{align*}
  &\dfix{A B}{C}
\end{align*}
% This also produces errors.
\begin{multline*}
  \dfix{A\\
    B}{C}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David! The parentheses are not needed inside the body of `\dfix`. The intention is that `$\dfix{f}{X}$` describes an operation on a functions f. When the first argument is a single letter, then no parentheses are needed (i.e., the output should be `$f^\ddag_X$`), but I was encountering issues when I had to split long function expression across several lines, e.g., `$\dfix{(A\\B)}{X}$`. Getting rid of the braces around `#1` as you did and changing the definition to `\newcommand{\dfix}[2]{#1^\ddag_{#2}}` seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: @RyanKavanagh OK I would never use that markup personally, having a macro argument start in one alignment cell and end in another is extremely weird, but as I show it's not technically invalid so if it does what you want, that's OK:-)